# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask project that I started 5 months ago and stopped after reg and authentication. I now want to proceed, after fresh installations, I am now getting the titled error with the login/authentication. Below

Account form

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Enter email', validators=[DataRequired(),Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Password')
```

In route file

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    formLogin = AccountForm.LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        return render_template('index.html',formLogin=formLogin)
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        if request.form.get('login', None)  == 'Login' :
            return AccountController.authenticatePopUpLogin(formLogin,'index')
```

In my accountcontroller

```
def authenticatePopUpLogin(formLogin,route):
    if formLogin.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == formLogin.email.data).first()
 except :# models.DoesNotExist:
            flash("Your email or password does not match !", "error")
            return render_template('login.html',form=formLogin,formLogin = formLogin)
        else :
            if check_password_hash(user.password,formLogin.password.data):
```

My User is imported from my model class

```
class User(UserMixin , Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(CHAR(3), nullable = False)
    firstname = Column(String(100), nullable = False)
    lastname = Column(String(100), nullable = False)
    DateOfBirth = Column(ArrowType, default = arrow.utcnow())
    username = Column(String(100), nullable = False, unique = True)
    email = Column (String(50), nullable =False, unique = True)
    password = Column(String(100), nullable = False) 
    ...
```

It then throws the error above. I am suspecting the error happens here `check_password_hash(user.password,formLogin.password.data):`. My form validation works however, it throws error when empty etc.

I confirmed the password field exist in my db as well. Please where do I go wrong?

Comment: I this line `if check_password_hash(user.password,formLogin.password.data):`, `user` is lower case whereas it's previously upper case.

Comment: Hi the `User` in the `session.query(User).filter(User.email == formLogin.email.data).first()` is from my User class. However , the `user` is from the variable `user`  (i.e `user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == formLogin.email.data).first()` . I think they are both lower cases sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`first`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first) method:

> Return the first result of this Query or `None` if the result doesn’t
>   contain any row.

So, you have to check if `user` is `None`.